# What's the equivalent of rubygems.org for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there an equivalent site for node that is like rubygems.org? How do people lookup available packages for npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**npmjs.org**

https://www.npmjs.org/

You can do searches from the command line too

```
$ npm search express
$ npm info express
```